# What is the derivative of $\dot{x} = f(x(t))$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am supposed to take the derivative of a function similar to this one: Take the derivative of $$\dot{x} = \cos(x)$$ where $x$ is a function of $t.$ I believe that this can be generalized to the phrasing that I used in my heading: What is the derivative of $$\dot{x} = f(x(t))?$$

Here is why I ask. I immediately took the derivative of both sides and got
$$\ddot{x} = -\sin(x).$$ Then I sat back and relaxed because that sure was simple! But since $x$ is actually $x(t),$ doesn't that change things? Is the derivative actually going to be
$$\ddot{x}(t) = -\sin(x(t))\cdot \dfrac{dx}{dt}$$ where $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = x'(t)$ or whatever notation people use. (I constantly get lost in the notation in multi-variable calculus/ODEs.)

Now, to be clear, I don't know what the $x(t)$ equation is, I just know that it exists. That's why I wanted to know the answer to the general case (additionally, this is similar to a homework problem and I didn't want someone to simply give me the answer).

Comment: Depends on whether you want the derivative in terms of the time or $x$. Which one is it?

Comment: @Sheheryar I don't know. All I know is that $x$ is a function of $t$ and that I'm to find $\ddot{x}$ when $\dot{x} = \cos(x).$

Comment: Your second expression for $\ddot{x}(t)$ is correct (note that the dot above indicates the derivative is with respect to $t$; this is common in physics). 

You are using the chain rule, which can be stated as $$(f\circ x)'(t) = f'(x(t))x'(t)$$ or $$\frac{d(f\circ x)}{dt}(t) = \frac{df}{dt}(x(t))\frac{dx}{dt}(t).$$

Furthermore, as $\dfrac{dx}{dt}(t) = \dot{x}(t)$, you can find an expression for $\ddot{x}(t)$ which only relies on $x(t)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\ddot{x}(t) = -\sin(x(t))\cdot \dfrac{dx}{dt}(t)$$ is the correct derivation. I was under the impression that $\dot{x}(t) = \frac{dx}{dt}(t)$ which means you can improve your derivation of $\ddot{x}(t)$ to  $$\ddot{x}(t) = -\sin(x(t))\cdot \cos(x(t))$$

Comment: I think that $\dot{x}(t) = \dfrac{dx}{dt}(t).$ At least that's what my intuition is telling me regarding all these symbols...

Comment: @Bark Jr. I learned that notation relatively recently so I just wanted to make sure. Was my attempt at this problem similar to what you got?

Comment: Yeah, I realized that right after I posted the comment question. That's why I deleted it. I suppose we still don't know what $x(t)$ is though, right? And we have no way of figuring out what it is with the given information, correct?

Comment: Ah whoops, I'll delete mine too then. I do not know how to solve for $x(t)$ off the top of my head. Do you have to do so?

Comment: No, I was just curious.